# Will Drupal & Drupal Commerce run under php-cgi?

Tags: commerce, installation

For some specific reasons (experimental setup - not Apache nor nginx) want run Drupal  under `php-cgi` (not fast-cgi). The site should serve an very-small e-commerce site - probably Drupal Commerce.

Based on my googling Drupal can run under `php-cgi`, but the found links are pretty old (2009 and such),  so looking for some answers for both of current main versions - for the `v7` and for the upcoming `v8`.

The questions are:

- Will Drupal (v7 and/or v8) run under `php-cgi`?
- Will run Drupal Commerce under `php-cgi`?
- are here some **major** limitations (other than speed!) caused using Drupal (and Drupal Commerce) with `php-cgi`?

Comment: I don't know, but install it, and fire up the tests. You'll know soon enough. :)

Comment: @Letharion just because I did't run into a problem immediately, doesn't mean that there are no (possible) problems. IMHO is better to ask drupal experts, as relying on my own "testing"... Or do you mean some special "test suite"?

Comment: I've posted an answer below, where I expanded on what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core in particular, but also Commerce, is extensively covered by automated tests.

Many of those are also run in a style that simulates a users journey, not only unit tests. So if you run those, you will have exercised essentially all relevant code.

There are some things that are not covered though, such as CSS and JS, although I strongly doubt those are affected by how you run the php interpreter.

Setup a Drupal instance, enable the `testing` module, and execute all the tests. Go read a book (as that will take a long time), and hope that you come back to all green. :)

Comment: Accepting this ;) mainly because meantime i managed an running (hm... mostly running) Drupal with php-cgi. So, for now i can say - it (mostly) works - and now i'm pretty sure than the problems are "fixable". (anyway, not tried yet the Drupal-commerce, but i doubt than someone could give an deeper and more accurate answer in this field. Thanx.